# HTML/JS/CSS optgroup

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am looking for a way to show all the selected options of an opt-group. as example:

```
<select name="select_projects" id="select_projects">
        <option value="">project.xml</option>
        <optgroup label="client1">
            <option value="">project2.xml</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="client2">
            <option value="">project5.xml</option>
            <option value="">project6.xml</option>
            <optgroup label="client2_a">
                <option value="" style="margin-left:23px;">project7.xml</option>
                <option value="" style="margin-left:23px;">project8.xml</option>
            </optgroup>
            <option value="">project3.xml</option>
            <option value="">project4.xml</option>
       </optgroup>
       <option value="">project0.xml</option>
       <option value="">project1.xml</option>
    </select>
```

This os my current optgroup and I want something like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi4q1.png)

I am looking for a way of achieving the image with jquery or javascript at all. I have no clue how to get multiple values of the dropdown displayed at top.

Comment: Too broad. What have you tried? Show some code, not HTML.

Comment: Well, you haven't actually given any of the options values, so there's nothing to get.  Also, you seem to be asking a couple different things and it's not exactly clear what your question really is. Are you asking how to _display_ previously-selected and stored values?  Or are you asking how to _get_ the selected values so that you can act on them?  Regardless, you're probably going to want a `multiple` select.  And to achieve the look in your image, you're going to need some CSS (or likely some library like bootstrap or jquery-ui)

Comment: My bad...I am looking for a method of solving the multiple select and showing the selected attributes at top of the dropdown.

Comment: That's purely a styling issue.  If you want it to look like that image, find out what library is being used on the site where you saw that.

Comment: isn't this achieved with javascript? Thought the multiple selection is a javascript this because it gives the server multiple values from the dropdown.

Comment: There is likely js involved in the styling (like I said, find out what library is being used in your pictured example), but in terms of being able to select multiple values, can be done with a native [`select multiple`](https://html.com/attributes/select-multiple/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution (maybe someone else needs something like this)...I used the following library: http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/
it was exactly what I were looking for.